# package is not available (for R version 2.15.2)

Tags: r

I am trying to install fEcofin package and I get the following message:

```
Warning message:
package ‘fEcofin’ is not available (for R version 2.15.2)
```

I have tried the following in R console and RStudio but to no avail. Is there a way I can install and use this package?

```
install.packages("fEcofin")
install.packages("fEcofin", type="source")
```

Comment: Try ```install.packages("fEcofin", repos = "http://r-forge.r-project.org/")```

Comment: @orizon You should make your comment into an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I have resolved this issue by manually adding 'RTextTools'