# rpart library package installation error on R 3.0.2

Tags: r, tree, machine-learning, decision-tree, cran

Command Issued:

```
install.packages("rpart")
```

Error:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/priyanka/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/src/contrib
Warning message:
package ‘rpart’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)
```

I have tried cloud-0 and Berkley CRAN site.
Please guide me on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried a different mirror?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik i also tried the india mirror. It hasnt helped

Comment: You can try that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15672906/2759357

Comment: Perhaps you're behind a firewall?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik yes it is the case, so what should i do now. And i have also tried  `Sys.setenv(http_proxy="http://proxy.example.com:8080")`